# Why is svn:ignore ignored?

Tags: svn

I just ran

```
svn add myfolder/*
```

To add all the files in there to my repo. It added the `.pyc` files too. I'm looking at my `svn:ignore` now and it says:

```
*.pyc
*~
```

Should that not have prevented those files from being checked in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it should not. `svn:ignore` prevents files from being shown in the `svn status`. But if you're adding the files explicitly - then `svn` will add them, of course.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Comment: Indeed. It's worth noting the OPs exact case is covered at the bottom of that article in a highlighted tip. (Wildcards).

Comment: @Noon Silk: oops, yes, i've added a link and forgot to specify that particular tip, thanks :-)

Comment: `svn add myfolder` would have been safe though. The problem is that the asterisk is expanded to individual file names, and it'll explicitly add all those files.